# Computing stirling's approximation of user input Python

Tags: python

i'm a massive python noob and have been tasked with

"Write a program that computes n factorial using Stirling’s approximation.
Your program should prompt the user to input a value for n and should then compute the Stirling Approximation for n! and output “The approximation is XXX which is YY of the exact answer” where XXX is the Stirling Approximation and YY is XXX/n!. (The value of YY should be close to 1 if the approximation is good.)"

i wrote

```
import math

n = input(int("Enter a value for n: ")

XXX = math.sqrt(2*math.pi*n)*(n/math.e)**n
YY = XXX/n          

print("The approximation is XXX which is YY of the exact answer")
```

this is probably completely wrong, whats a simple way to do it?

Comment: I see a syntax error in your line with the `input` statement (missing right parentheses). And, you should be doing your `int` type cast around the input, not inside. Also, your print statement at the end is not outputting the vlaues of `XXX` and `YY`

Comment: `print("The approximation is {0} which is {1} of the exact answer".format(XXX,YY))`

Comment: Overall very nice for a first try. Why don't you give your own answer based on the help you got.

Comment: well i gotimport math

n = int(input("Enter a value for n: "))

XXX = math.sqrt(2*math.pi*n)*(n/math.e)**n
YY = XXX/n          

print("The approximation is {0} which is {1} of the exact answer".format(XXX,YY))

Answer (score 0):

this might help you

```
import NumPy as np
def f(n):
    if (np.sqrt((2*np.pi)) *n**( (n+.5))*np.exp(-n) < np.math.factorial(n) \
        <np.sqrt((2*np.pi)) *n**( (n+.5))*np.exp(-n+1/(12*n))):
        print("Stirling is true")
    else:
        print("Something is wrong")
```

And for example set n = 5

```
f(5)
```